# NextJS / Contentful Category and Subcategory setup for blog

Tags: next.js

The is my current nextjs structure:

```
> pages
>> [cslug]
>>> index.js
>>> [scslug]
>>>>[post].js
>>>> index.js
```

[image]

I am using contentful for my content, there are 2 category fields for my articles, category and subcategory. In some instances an article will only have a main category but no subcategory in this, to explain this in terms of URLs if the article only has a main category the URL would be

[www.example.com/maincategory/article](http://www.example.com/maincategory/article)

If it also has a sub category the URL would be

[www.example.com/maincategory/subcategory/article](http://www.example.com/maincategory/subcategory/article)

This currently doesn't function with the way I have built the project as the /subcategory/ page will only show subcategories and not content, because of how the pages are coded. I will show you the code below, if you can help solve this, that would be great.

[cslug]/index.js

```
import React from 'react'

import { client } from '@/utils/contentful'

import CategoryLayout from '@/components/categories/CategoryLayout'
import CategoryBlocks from '@/components/categories/CategoryBlocks'
import ResponsiveLeaderboard from '@/components/adverts/ResponsiveLeaderboard'

export default function CSlugHome({categroyPages}) {
  const breadcrumbs = [[categroyPages[0].fields.category.fields.slug,categroyPages[0].fields.category.fields.name]]
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CategoryLayout breadcrumbs={breadcrumbs} >
        <ResponsiveLeaderboard />
        <div className='grid grid-cols-12 gap-4 m-4 lg:my-4 lg:mx-0'>
          {categroyPages.map((items) => {
            return(
              <CategoryBlocks key={items.fields.slug} items={items} />
            )})
          }
        </div>
      </CategoryLayout>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const { cslug } = params;
  const response = await client.getEntries({
      content_type: "pages",
      "fields.category.sys.contentType.sys.id": "categories",
      "fields.category.fields.slug": cslug,
  });
  return {
      props: {
          categroyPages: response?.items,
      },
      revalidate: 60,
  };
}


export async function getStaticPaths(){
  const response = await client.getEntries({ content_type: "categories"});
  const paths = response.items.map((item) => ({
      params: { 
        cslug: item.fields.slug,
      },
  }));
  return {
      paths,
      fallback: false,
  }
}
```

*[cslug]/[scslug]/index.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import { client } from '@/utils/contentful'

import CategoryLayout from '@/components/categories/CategoryLayout'
import CategoryBlocks from '@/components/categories/CategoryBlocks'
import ResponsiveLeaderboard from '@/components/adverts/ResponsiveLeaderboard'
import NoContentInCategory from '@/components/categories/NoContentInCategory';

export default function SCSlugHome({ subcategory, cslug, scslug }) {
    if (!subcategory || subcategory.length === 0) {
        return(
            <NoContentInCategory cslug={cslug} scslug={scslug} />
        );
    }
    const categoryName = subcategory[0].fields.subcategory.fields.name
    const breadcrumbs = [[subcategory[0].fields.category.fields.slug,subcategory[0].fields.category.fields.name],[subcategory[0].fields.subcategory.fields.slug,subcategory[0].fields.subcategory.fields.name]]
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <CategoryLayout breadcrumbs={breadcrumbs}>
                <ResponsiveLeaderboard />
                <div className='grid grid-cols-12 gap-4 m-4 lg:my-4 lg:mx-0'>
                    {subcategory.map((items) => {
                        return(
                            <CategoryBlocks key={items.fields.slug} items={items} />
                        )})
                    }
                </div>
            </CategoryLayout>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}


export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    const { cslug } = params;
    const { scslug } = params;
    const response = await client.getEntries({
        content_type: "pages",
        "fields.category.sys.contentType.sys.id": "categories",
        "fields.category.fields.slug": cslug,
        "fields.subcategory.sys.contentType.sys.id": "subcategories",
        "fields.subcategory.fields.slug": scslug,
    });
    return {
        props: {
            subcategory: response?.items,
            cslug: cslug,
            scslug: scslug
        },
        revalidate: 60,
    };
}


export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const response = await client.getEntries({ 
        content_type: "categories",
    });
    const paths = response.items.map(category => {
        const cslug = category.fields.slug;
        const subcategories = category.fields.subcategory;     
        const subPaths = subcategories.map(subcategory => ({
                params: {
                    cslug,
                    scslug: subcategory.fields.slug
                }
            }));
            return subPaths;
    }).flat();
    return {
        paths,
        fallback: false,
    };
}
```

*[cslug]/[scslug]/[post].js*

```
import React from 'react'
import { client } from '@/utils/contentful'
import { documentToReactComponents } from '@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer';

import ArticleLayout from '@/components/articles/ArticleLayout'
import ResponsiveLeaderboard from '@/components/adverts/ResponsiveLeaderboard'
import ArticleMetadata from '@/components/articles/ArticleMetadata';

export default function Post({post, cslug, scslug}) {
  const slug = post[0].fields.slug
  const category = post[0].fields.category.fields.slug
  const categoryName = post[0].fields.category.fields.name
  const subcategoryName = post[0].fields.subcategory.fields.name
  const subcategorySlug = post[0].fields.subcategory.fields.slug
  const title = post[0].fields.title
  const banner = post[0].fields.banner.fields.file.url
  const bannerAlt = post[0].fields.banner.fields.title
  const content = post[0].fields.content
  const updatedAt = post[0].sys.updatedAt
  const createdAt = post[0].sys.createdAt
  const breadcrumbs = [[category,categoryName],[subcategorySlug,subcategoryName],[slug,title]]
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ArticleMetadata postDetails={post[0]} />
      <ArticleLayout breadcrumbs={breadcrumbs}>
        <ResponsiveLeaderboard />
        <div className='mx-4'>
          <div className='mt-4 mb-8'>
            <div className='mb-4'>
              <h1>{title}</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
              <img className='w-full h-auto max-h-[225px] md:max-h-[300px] object-cover shadow-xl' src={banner} alt={bannerAlt} />        
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className='grid grid-cols-12 gap-4'>
            <div className='col-span-1 hidden lg:block'>
              <div className='flex justify-center'>S</div>
              <div className='flex justify-center'>O</div>
              <div className='flex justify-center'>C</div>
              <div className='flex justify-center'>I</div>
              <div className='flex justify-center'>A</div>
              <div className='flex justify-center'>L</div>
              <div className='flex justify-center'>S</div>
            </div>          
            <div className='col-span-12 lg:col-span-11 lg:mr-4'>
              {documentToReactComponents(content)}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ArticleLayout>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const { cslug } = params;
  const { scslug } = params;
  const { post } = params;
  const response = await client.getEntries({
    content_type: "pages",
    "fields.category.sys.contentType.sys.id": "categories",
    "fields.category.fields.slug": cslug,
    "fields.subcategory.sys.contentType.sys.id": "subcategories",
    "fields.subcategory.fields.slug": scslug,
    "fields.slug": post,
  });
  return {
      props: {
          post: response?.items,
          cslug,
          scslug
      },
      revalidate: 60,
  };
}


export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const response = await client.getEntries({ 
      content_type: "pages",
  });
  const paths = response.items.map(category => {
      const cslug = category.fields.category.fields.slug;
      const scslug = category.fields.subcategory.fields.slug;
      const post = category.fields.slug;
      return({
        params: {
            cslug,
            scslug,
            post
        }
      })
  })
  return {
      paths,
      fallback: false,
  };
}
```

I think the main problem, is the current [cslug]/[scslug]/index.js file is only setup to generate paths for sub categories and not if it doesn't have subcategories but is an article.